# Git command to get all folders with changes

Tags: git, bash

I am trying to figure out what is the git command to get all the folders with changes in them.

```
git diff --name-only
```

But this gives all the actual files that changed?

Comment: If it's A/B/C/aaa.txt that's changed, which folder do you want? A/ or A/B/C/ or else?

Comment: I want all the subdirectory names from the root git folder. so basically A/ if that's the root git repository and what should be returned is the folder names inside of A/

Comment: try this `git log --pretty="go-away:%h" --name-only | grep -v go-away: | grep / | awk -F / '{print $1}' | sort -u`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the paths containing changes, pipe the output through `xargs` to `dirname`

```
git diff --name-only | xargs dirname | uniq
```

This will strip all the filenames from the relative paths and remove any duplicates.

For example:

```
$ git diff --name-only
app/lib/sub/dirlist.cpp
app/net/rpc.cpp
config/config.txt
```

after `dirname` will return

```
$ git diff --name-only | xargs dirname | uniq
app/lib/sub
app/net
config
```

`xargs` takes multiple lines (list outputs) and runs the following command (`dirname` in this example) on each in turn. `uniq` will remove duplicates from the output.

Comment: You may want to add `| uniq`, to discard duplicates.  (Sorting is not necessary as Git traverses in its internal tree order, which is sorted.)

Comment: For OSX use "xargs -n1 dirname" since OSX's dirname only allows for one argument.  The -n1 of xargs takes one line at a time from stdin and passes it to dirname.